# How use rowspan dinamic in bucle rowspan in angular html

Tags: html, angular, html-table, frontend

My problem is this. I'm creating a dynamic matrix

when i use the rowspan to group i guess i create the first group of 2 , where it has to span A AND B. it does but when i create another group. it starts from B which shouldn't [Picture Exapamle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSj5Z.png) happen since the rowspan only covers A AND B and then it should include the other group B and C but I see that it starts from B through the for loop could you help me.

`
I am using the arr.rowspan to be able to put the names but when I group in 2 or 3, it is not working because of the for loop

```
      <tbody>
                <!-- Agrega tus filas y celdas dinámicamente aquí -->
                
                <tr *ngFor="let fila of objEdit.obj.filas; let filaIndex = index">
                  <ng-container *ngIf="objEdit.obj.gruposFila[filaIndex] && objEdit.obj.gruposFila.length > 0 "> 
                    <th [attr.rowspan]="objEdit.obj.gruposFila[filaIndex].tamano">{{ objEdit.obj.gruposFila[filaIndex].nombre }}</th>
                  </ng-container>
                  
                  <!-- Celdas vacías para las filas sin rowspan -->
                  <ng-container *ngIf="!objEdit.obj.gruposFila[filaIndex] || objEdit.obj.gruposFila.length === 0">
                    <th></th>
           
       </ng-container>
                  
                  <th>{{ fila }}</th>
                  <td [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': valoresCeldas[filaIndex][columnaIndex].color }"
                    *ngFor="let columna of objEdit.obj.columnas; let columnaIndex = index">
                    <input [(ngModel)]="valoresCeldas[filaIndex][columnaIndex].valor" type="number" min="0" max="5" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
```

My idea is that the names of the groups appear in the same column without pushing anything